# How to add padding/margin to move :after up

Tags: css, margin, padding

I am trying to move an `:after` up, so that it sits more in line with the top of the element it is besides. I've tried adding `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`, adding `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, but none of these work.

```
#myDiv:after {
  color: #D03540;
  content: " *";
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply position property value of absolute to the `#myDiv:after` then set to desired position with `Top`, `Bottom`, `Left` and `Right` property values.

```
#myDiv {
   position: relative; /* To curtail overlap */
}

#myDiv:after {
   color: #D03540;
   content: " *";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;  /* Adjust as needed */
   left: 0; /* Adjust as needed */
   right:0; /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

Comment: You can also use relative position

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! I just used it without `right:40;` and not the `top` or the `right`.